# Gremlin Server connect to Orient DB

Tags: python-3.x, gremlin, tinkerpop3, orientdb2.2, gremlin-server

I start my Gremlin NEO4J like this

```
./gremlin-server.sh conf/gremlin-server-neo4j.yaml
```

I have installed OrientDB Community edition and it seems to be working file via IP:2480/studio/index.htm

Now I am trying to connect my Gremlin Server to Orient DB but I dont find any way to achieve it

**Python code to connect with Gremlin Server**

```
from gremlin_python.driver import client as driver

# Constants for connections to gremlin
GREMLIN_VAR = 'g'
GREMLIN_URL = 'ws://localhost:8182/gremlin'
client = driver.Client(GREMLIN_URL, GREMLIN_VAR)
```

**What I found but didnt help**

1. [V3 doc](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/tinkerpop3/OrientDB-TinkerPop3.html) but they are using Java and not Python
2. [orientdb-server-config.xml](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/blob/master/tests-scala/config/orientdb-server-config.xml)  but I need a **yaml** file for python
3. *gremlin-server.sh -i org.apache.tinkerpop orientdb-gremlin 3.3.1* threw an error '[unresolved dependency: org.apache.tinkerpop#orientdb-gremlin;3.3.1: not found]'
4. 'orientdb-community-importers-2.2.31/bin' has a file called 'gremlin.sh' it executed but I am unable to do something like g = graph.traversal()

   5. Tried "./gremlin-server.sh -i com.orientechnologies orientdb-gremlin 2.2.31" it installed something but I dont know how to go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I understood to see the configurations that you are using a very old version of `orientdb` use `orientdb-gremlin 3.0.2` in the latest version they embedded gremlin with orientdb and for download dependencies use this `./gremlin-server.sh -i com.orientechnologies orientdb-gremlin 3.0.2`

based on more information from OP, added

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientFactory
orient-url=plocal:txt/GremlinServer
orient-user=admin
orient-pass=admin
```

hope this will help you

thank you

Comment: also I tried connecting with orient db folder, (same password with which I created the database from orient db), and the server was hanging. any ideas what I am doing wrong

Comment: can you send me your `orientdb-empty.properties`

Comment: just this gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientGraph

Comment: i tried this in my system and its working fine might be the problem is happing becz you didnt put the password and username, just do one thing update your `orientdb-empty.properties`

Comment: I put the correct password that I created the orient db root user.

Comment: Did you try with `admin`

Comment: oh thank somehow orientdb has hard-coded the password. thanks